# Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher while building Maven 3.0.4

Tags: java, linux, apache, maven, ubuntu

I have used `apt-get install maven2` to install *maven2.2.1*. In order to compile *hadoop 2.1.0* source program, I need to upgrade the *maven* version, but it is not able to use `apt-get` again, because *maven2.1.0* is the latest in the lib.

I downloaded `apache-maven-3.0.5-bin.tar.gz` from the official website, ran `tar apache-maven-3.0.5-bin.tar.gz` at the path `/usr/local`, and put `apache-maven` links to *apache-maven-3.0.5*:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   18 Dec  8 11:26 apache-maven -> apache-maven-3.0.5
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 1024 Dec  8 11:12 apache-maven-3.0.5

export the order in the terminal like this:
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

input order "export" to identify :

```
.............................................
declare -x M2_HOME="/usr/local/apache-maven"
declare -x MANDATORY_PATH="/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path"
declare -x OLDPWD="/usr"
declare -x PATH="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/java/latest/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/apache-maven/bin"
```

All signs showed *maven 3.0.5* has succeeded in configuration, but when I input

`mvn -version`

in the terminal, it show errors like this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher
```

If I change a new terminal and input `mvn -version`, it shows:

```
administrator@ubuntu:~$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8)
Java version: 1.7.0_45
Java home: /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "3.5.0-17-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

It happens every time although I had uninstalled *maven 2.2.1* by running:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge maven`

I do not know why? I have not uninstalled it completely?

Answer (score 5):

The below answer (setting M3_HOME instead of M2_HOME) solved my issue
http://www.johnlabarge.com/post/33156663109/dreaded-maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

> I had this little issue on my Mac after installing maven3 and jdk1.7.  Here is what fixed my issue:
>
> 1) Remove the M2_HOME variable from the path.
>
> 2) Add M3_HOME variable with the path to your maven 3 installation.
>
> Here is the interesting part: I use symbolic links for versioning.  The values of both M2_HOME and M3_HOME were identical.  Both were /Developer/maven.  Hence it appears that the name M2_HOME in place of M3_HOME is what actually causes the issue.  I leave it as an exercise (that I may return to) to find the issue in the source.

Comment: +1. I just had this issue upgrading from Maven 2 to 3 on Windows. It wasn't enough to eradicate all mention of the maven 2 install from the path, I also had to nuke the M2_HOME variable as well.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend a fresh installation of maven. First , remove all installations of all versions of maven from your system

`$ sudo apt-get remove maven`

Next, instead of downloading from the package manager, download it from the offical Apache website. I would recommend getting the latest version of maven (3.1.X), and extract it in a directory where you have read/write privileges.

`$ tar -xvf apache-maven-3.1.1.tar.gz`

Lastly update all symlinks and home variables set for maven. You have a choice of defining the environment variables.

1. `/etc/environment` -> Some people don't recomment setting global variables here due to obvious reasons.
2. `/etc/bashrc` -> I personally use this to export any environment variables I want.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer,I have solved the problem,I should  use apt-get remove maven2 to remove the installed maven2.2.1,and the clean the configuration of this installed maven2.2.1.the using apt-get install maven could install maven3.0+ version.

Comment: Thank you very much - also to install from scratch https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-apache-maven-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 4):

I got this error too. Turns out I had forgotten to restart my shell.

Once I closed Terminal and opened it again, the error did not come back  and Maven worked.

Comment: Restarting the shell did the trick here. What's the cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in Windows 8 but in my case maven directory e.g apache-maven-3.3.3 was hidden.

Post removing hidden option from the directory apache-maven-3.3.3 worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

Solved for me on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove maven

$ sudo apt-get purge maven

$ sudo apt-get install maven
```