# eclipse m2eclipse not working

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, m2e

the m2eclipse plugin is latest
the eclipse is the latest 
the JDK is jdk7
the eclipse uses embedded maven version 3.xxx

I am keep getting this error “Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher”

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**my envirement**
<kbd>eclipse version : 4.3 kepler</kbd>

<kbd>maven version : 3.2.x</kbd>

<kbd>OS : windows 7</kbd>

<kbd>m2e plugin version : 1.5</kbd>

the problem caused by combination of things, e.g mismatch between maven installation and setting.xml is one, but mainly the problem was:

solution for my problem was to run the eclipse **in administrator mode**.

you can run maven embedded (comes with eclipse) or external installation 
  just to make sure they are pointing to the right setting.xml file

somehow the embedded disappears sometimes, just restart eclipse it will appear again

finally I can confirm the latest m2e 1.5 or above supports maven 3.

**Note:**

set JAVA_HOME is a must, because maven uses it to look up java which runs maven itself

set non-embeded maven installation location in the windows path is needed

set M2_HOME was **NOT** needed in my case, thus to get m2e working in eclipse or interact maven though command line, M2_HOME is not needed

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there are some problems running the embedded Maven.

Try [installing a fresh Maven version](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi), then click `Preferences` , `Maven`, `Installations`and set the directory where you have installed Maven.
[image]

Comment: i can see its a maven2 from your example. does the latest eclipse support maven 3? reason I ask is because I did the same step as your answer but my local installation is mvn3. and the eclipse thrown a no embedded maven found error

Comment: The image is taken from the [Developing with Eclipse and Maven](http://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/preferences.html#fig-preferences-maven-installations) and in our team the "m2e" plugin is used with external Maven 3.1.1, 3.2.1 installation. I've done a fresh installation of "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" and "m2e" and pointing my external Maven without any problems. You'd better open an issue or ask to [m2eclipse - Support](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/support/).

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118237/maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-codehaus-plexus-classworlds-l) and  [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449836/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-codehaus-classworlds-launcher-while)?

Comment: @taringamerini thanks but both question wasn't answered

Comment: thanks for your help my friend. +1 for being so helpful

Comment: @shanyangqu Thank you for sharing your solution. I've appreciated your +1 too because I do the same thing with others: when some answers don't solve my problem but help me to find a solution a give +1 to all of them. This community stands on users feedback.