# finding maven version & set MAVEN_HOME in ubuntu

Tags: java, maven

I think I have jumbled up something. yesterday things were working fine. Having lots of problems today..

1.I ran this command

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
```

then

```
mvn --version
Error: Could not find or load main class    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

yesterday it was working fine (returning maven version, 3.0.4 , I think) . Now this has started creating problems. what to do ?

2. Also after running

   $java --version
    Unrecognized option: --version
    Could not create the Java virtual machine.

here is the content of my .bashrc file and I have nothing in my /etc/environment file.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

and this is in my /etc/profile

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
PATH=$PATH:$HOME:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

3. Also let me know, how can i set MAVEN_HOME in it..

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449836/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-codehaus-classworlds-launcher-while

Comment: @Imran in that link , the person is able to run java --version command. but I am not..:( Also thats for windows... and I am using ubuntu...

Comment: There's no need to add JAVA_HOME to the path, it's only required as environment variable. Also, never set the M2_HOME variable (if you did), the mvn shellscript will set it for you. And to question 3, just add `apache-maven-3.0.4/bin` to the `path`.

Comment: @RobertScholte you mean I should remove JAVA_HOME from .bashrc and put it in etc/environment or just remove JAVA_HOME ? I dint set M2_HOME variable.. could you please tell in a bit more detail about the third question.. like how exactly to set it (in .bashrc or environment or profile)...

Comment: You should remove these line: `PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME` and `PATH=$PATH:$HOME:$JAVA_HOME/bin`. Maven is always looking for this variable, it doesn't resolve it from the path. The other thing you need to do is `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.3/bin` to be able to run the `mvn` shell-scripts without having to specify the absolute path.

Comment: when I run this, **$whereis mvn**

I get it... 

**mvn: /usr/bin/mvn /usr/bin/X11/mvn /usr/share/man/man1/mvn.1.gz** 

and when I run this .. **whereis maven**

I get 

**maven: /etc/maven /usr/share/maven**

so what should be PATH= ?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe my config gives you a hint:

```
/$ uname -a
Linux jenkins 3.2.0-55-generic #85-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 2 12:29:27 UTC 2013 \
  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

/$ echo $PATH
/var/lib/jenkins/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin

/$ ls -l /usr/bin/java* / usr/bin/mvn*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Feb 21  2013 java -> /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Feb 21  2013 javac -> /etc/alternatives/javac
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Feb 21  2013 javaws -> /etc/alternatives/javaws
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Feb 21  2013 mvn -> /etc/alternatives/mvn
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Feb 21  2013 mvnDebug -> /etc/alternatives/mvnDebug

/$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java* /etc/alternatives/mvn*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 May 31  2013 /etc/alternatives/java -> \
  /opt/jdk/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 May 31  2013 /etc/alternatives/javac -> \
  /opt/jdk/bin/javac
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 58 Feb 21  2013 /etc/alternatives/javaws.1.gz -> \
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/javaws.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Feb 21  2013 /etc/alternatives/mvn -> \
  /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Feb 21  2013 /etc/alternatives/mvn.1.gz -> \
  /usr/share/maven/man/mvn.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Feb 21  2013 /etc/alternatives/mvnDebug -> \
  /usr/share/maven/bin/mvnDebug
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Feb 21  2013 /etc/alternatives/mvnDebug.1.gz -> \
  /usr/share/maven/man/mvnDebug.1.gz
```

---

`/usr/share/maven/conf/m2.conf`:

```
main is org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli from plexus.core

set maven.home default ${user.home}/m2

[plexus.core]
optionally ${maven.home}/lib/ext/*.jar
load       ${maven.home}/lib/*.jar
```

---

```
/$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)

/$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_21, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /opt/jdk1.7.0_21/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-55-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: thanks :) I was doing just one mistake of java --version (it should be  single dash) otherwise things have started working fine itself in office.

Answer (score 1):

there was just one mistake that was java --version. It should be java -version (single dash)
 otherwise it is working fine now...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.johnlabarge.com/post/33156663109/dreaded-maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class This link could help, just remove the M2_HOME variable, then add M3_HOME variable.

BTW, to print Java version no, you should enter `java -version`, rather than `java --version`, only single dash is needed, but with Maven, both 'mvn -version' and `mvn --version` are ok.

Comment: yes.. java --version was wrong... already corrected it.. but thanx.. and without changing anything.. mvn --version has also started working fine in office... :D